# Word or phrase for "shooting an arrow with a bow"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, expression-choice, phrase-requests

What's the right way to refer to the act of using a bow and an arrow to shoot?

Imagine a situation, in which Jack gave a bow and an arrow to John and asked him to shoot. John did, but since he had no experience in using bows and arrows, he accidentally injured their friend Lily.

Now imagine Jack and John twenty years later visiting Michael in his house (Michael has no knowledge of the incident) and reflecting on their life:

Jack says to John and Michael: "Throughout all these years that we've been friends I have never put you in troubles and never asked you to do anything stupid"

John replies: "Really? You forgot how you asked me to _____________________ while I had no experience in that, and eventually, Lily was almost killed?"

Please, note that the phrase is spoken in Michael's presence. On one hand, Michael has no knowledge of the accident; on the other hand, the phrase must be clear enough for Michael to understand what exactly had happened 20 years ago.

None of the options that I can think of seems to be fine:

1) "... how you asked me **to shoot an arrow from a bow** while I had no experience ..."

2) "... how you asked me **to shoot an arrow with a bow** while I had no experience ..."

3) "... how you asked me **to shoot an arrow using a bow** while I had no experience ..."

4) "... how you asked me **to shoot a bow** while I had no experience ..."

5) "... how you asked me **to shoot an arrow** while I had no experience ..."

6) "... how you asked me **to shoot from a bow** while I had no experience ..."

7) "... how you asked me **to shoot an arrow** while I had no experience ..."

8) "... how you asked me **to send an arrow from a bow** while I had no experience ..."

9) "... how you asked me **to send an arrow with a bow** while I had no experience ..."

10) "... how you asked me **to send an arrow using a bow** while I had no experience ..."

11) "... how you asked me **to shoot a bow arrow** while I had no experience ..."

12) "... how you asked me **to send a bow arrow** while I had no experience ..."

Comment: #5 looks the best of this dozen.

Comment: I'm not an expert (never actually shot a real bow and arrow), but often descriptions of the action go in several steps -- "nocking" the arrow onto the bowstring, drawing back the bowstring, and releasing.

Comment: @Lawrence Not without reason. You could expand on that for an answer.

Comment: You don't need to mention bow at all, because you can only shoot an arrow with a bow and no way else anyway. So "to shoot an arrow" says enough and says everything.

Comment: Trivia: You can even "fire an arrow" go figure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the simple:

> . . . how you asked me to use a bow and arrow . . .

However, assuming that there was an *object* that had been shot at (lets assume it was a tree), I think it would more naturally be:

> . . . how you asked me to shoot that tree with a bow and arrow . . .

---

To expand on this, you say that you *shoot a gun* or *shoot something with a gun* but you don't (normally) say that you *shoot a bullet (from a gun)* or *shoot something with a bullet (from a gun)*.

As far as phrasing goes, *bow and arrow* is used in the same type of way as *gun*.

---

**Update**: As per a comment, these would be the more common phrases used in the absence of each weapon's direct object:

> I was taught how to fire a gun.
> I was taught how to shoot a bow and arrow.

Comment: What do you think about "...how you asked me to shoot an arrow..."?

Comment: @brilliant I personally don't think it sounds natural—although I think it's the *most* natural from those choices . . .

Comment: I agree with your very first statement. However, we do say: You asked me to shoot an arrow at that tree. And that option is not provided by the OP.

Comment: @Lambie It *can* be said, but I would find it unnatural. I'm used to more often hearing, *You asked me to shoot at that tree (with a bow and arrow).*

Comment: @JasonBassford Same idea exactly. None of the OP's options include a direct object. "You asked me to shoot bullets at the can." These direct object options are natural sounding.

Comment: @Lambie Okay, I've updated my answer to mention that more explicitly.

Comment: @Lambie: "However, we do say: You asked me to shoot an arrow at that tree. And that option is not provided by the OP" - Unless I misunderstood something here, why do you say that that option is not provided in my question. Isn't that the option #5?

Comment: @brilliant  No, shoot an arrow ***at [something]*** is in none of your suggestions.

Comment: @Lambie: Ah, now I see what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the british magazine Archery World the correct term is [shoot the bow](https://www.archeryworld.co.uk/shooting-the-bow) (as opposed to shooting the arrow). However this is probably only used by serious archers and may not be used at all in other countries.

The main term to avoid, though, is "firing an arrow" which is often heard but is very much incorrect since neither gunpowder nor fire is used to propel an arrow from a bow. You can shoot a gun, shoot a bullet, shoot a bow or shoot an arrow; what you can't do is fire an arrow.

Comment: One could argue that since "firing an arrow" is often heard it is indeed correct.

Comment: @aslum I suppose you could, but only by accepting that "to fire" has become an exact synonym of "to shoot". This would be to accept the removal of a valuable distinction between the verbs. I, personally, claim that it is impossible to "fire" an air rifle since no fire is involved, although I will admit that that is, possibly, a bit over-pedantic.

Comment: Also then you couldn't fire a laser pistol or atomic rifle or death Ray either.

Comment: @aslum Possibly not, although those weapons all use heat as to cause damage to the target. Arrows, air rifle pellets, bb gun balls, paint balls and stones from catapults and slings use kinetic energy to do the damage and that kinetic energy is provided without using fire or explosives.

Comment: But you don't "air" and Airsoft or paintball gun... You fire it, but there's no fire invovled. That's like saying using a microwave isn't cooking or using skype on your phone isn't calling someone.

Comment: @aslum You don't "air" an airgun, you don't "elastic" a catapult, you _shoot_ them, just as you do a bow. You can also _shoot_ (or more commonly _shoot with_) a firearm but, in the specific case of a firearm or large gun where the projectile is propelled by explosive you can _also_ "fire" it. My point is that _shoot_ is the general term for the use of all projectile weapons which use stored energy to propel the projectile and that _fire_ is an alternative verb relating only to those weapons which use fire of some sort as the propellant force.

Comment: So counter example... Dry-fire an airsoft is when you fire it without ammo... You don't Dry-shoot an airsoft gun.

Comment: @aslum That's acceptable, the principle of airsoft is that it is emulation of conflict with firearms. In that context _firing_ is reasonable, and I'm admitting to being a bit pedantic with respect to firearm-like weapons. The usage that gets under my skin is talking about "firing" arrows from bows and stones from catapults which have no connection with firearms at all.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use "loose an arrow" or "release the arrow" as it only pertains to archery. While I think "to shoot an arrow" would be most commonly used, I have a hard time "shooting an arrow" while we say "shooting a gun", and not "shoot a bullet". So maybe he shot the bow? Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Release an arrow. Shoot the bow. Like "Shoot the gun "
I once used, draw your bow. That pertains to readying yourself though, and beginning the pull to prepare for release.

Quite rightly, Longfellow did not feel it necessary to mention the bow - that is assumed.

Comment: This answer would be improved by citations from reputable references.

Answer (score 0):

The correct term would be to "loose" an arrow.

"The archer drew back his bow and let loose an arrow."
"The archers loosed a hail of arrows."

However, in modern terms, most people would recognize "shoot" as an acceptable word!

Comment: Hello, Daniel, and welcome! Thank you for your contribution. You could improve it by adding an attributed quote from an authoritative work (like a dictionary) explaining why this answer is right (according to the guidelines given at https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please take the tour at https://english.stackexchange.com/tour, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

"The Arrow and the Song" By Henry Wadsworth Longfellow *I shot an arrow into the air, / It fell to earth, I knew not where;*